# Extending dart class similar to js prototyping or swift extension

Tags: dart

Extending class that provided to me. Giving a new functionality to already existing classes. Or extending already existing `mixin`s or virtual classes, anything can work.
Maybe something like:

```dart
    class FlatButton {} // maybe not defined by me
    mixin on FlatButton {
        roundCorner(int pixels) {
            //...
        } 
    }

    final button = FlatButton();
    button.roundCorner(10)
```

Swift/Kotlin support this by `extension` keyword or js with `prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/177) about this on dartlang repo. It is still open and don't think it is possible for now.